# Android BLE peripheral device data receiving

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, light

This might sound really basic but I'm a beginner at Android BLE Development. 
So far I am able to Create my Nexus 9 device as a peripheral device and Moto G as Central. Plus i'm connecting the devices successfully. But i cant figure out that when i send a characteristic from central device where will it be received from peripheral? The Advertise call back only return if advertisement is started successfully of not(Which in my case is successful)

Here is my peripheral Code

```
        btleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

         @Override
            // Result of a characteristic read operation
            public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                    int status) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
                }
            }        
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status, final int newState) { 
            // this will get called when a device connects or disconnects
        }

        @Override
        // New services discovered
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w("doscover", "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }
        };

BeaconParser bp = new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0,i:4-19,p:20-20");

        mBeaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(this, bp );

        // Transmit a beacon with Identifiers 2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6 1 2
        Long li = new Long(-0l);
        ArrayList<Long> l = new ArrayList<Long>();
        l.add(li);
        Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()

                  .setId1("2F234454-CF6D-4A0F-ADF2-F4911BA9FFA6")
                  .setId2("1")
                  .setId3("2")
                  .setManufacturer(0x00ff) // Choose a number of 0x00ff or less as some devices cannot detect beacons with a manufacturer code > 0x00ff
                  .setTxPower(-59)
                  .setDataFields(l)
                  .build();

        mBeaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon);
```

And the Central Code ofcorse

```
    btManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) ;
    madapter = btManager.getAdapter();
    if (madapter != null && !madapter.isEnabled()) {
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);   
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent,1);
    }
    mHandler = new Handler();

    btleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

         @Override
            // Result of a characteristic read operation
            public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic,
                    int status) {
                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    broadcastUpdate(ACTION_DATA_AVAILABLE, characteristic);
                }
            }        
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status, final int newState) { 
            Log.w("doscover", "Connected " + status);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            Log.w("discover", "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                broadcastUpdate(ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED);
            } else {
                Log.w("doscover", "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
            }
        }






    };


    devicefound = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();
    devices = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this , R.layout.device_name);
    ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    pairedListView.setAdapter(devices);

     mleScanCallback = new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, final byte[] scanRecord) {
                    devicefound.add(device);

                        //UUID = device.getAddress().toString();
                        //Log.e("Search", "" + device.getName().toString() );
                        //Toast`.makeText(context,device.getName().toString(), 1 ).show();
                        Log.e("Search", "" + device.toString());
                        Log.e("Search", "" + String.valueOf(rssi)  );


                            devices.add("Nex" + device.getName() );

                            //mBluetoothGatt = device.connectGatt(getActivity(), true, btleGattCallback);        




            }
        };

        pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1,
                    int position, long id) {


                 dv = devicefound.get(position);

                 mBluetoothGatt = dv.connectGatt(getApplicationContext() , true, btleGattCallback);        
                 mBluetoothGatt.connect();
                 dv.createBond();

                 //BluetoothDevice dd = madapter.getRemoteDevice(devicefound.get(position).getAddress());
                if(i == false)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service found. Connected to " + dv.getName() , 1).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already Connected " + dv.getName() , 1).show();

                }
                 i = mBluetoothGatt.connect();

                mBluetoothGatt.beginReliableWrite();

                boolean b = mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
                Log.e("Discovery Started", "" + b );
                     Log.e("get ItemATPosition", "" + adapter.getItemAtPosition(position));

                     //BluetoothGattService Service = mBluetoothGatt.getService(  );
                     // = Service.getCharacteristic(k);

                     BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic= new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(k,2,1); //Service
                     characteristic.setValue( "This is a Charects ");



                     byte[] value = {(byte)91,(byte)92,(byte)93};

                     characteristic.setValue(value); 

                     boolean st = mBluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic(characteristic); 
                     //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t1.getText() + " " + st, 1).show();
                     boolean b1 = mBluetoothGatt.executeReliableWrite();


                     //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), t1.getText() + " " + b1, 1).show();
                     Intent in = new Intent("ACTION_BOND_STATE_CHANGED.");
                    sendBroadcast(in);

            }
        });
        scanLeDevice(true);
```

I'm using the writeCharacteristic command of the connected Gatt from central but dont know how to receive from Peripheral end

Any sort of Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

peripheral mode may support good on IOS, I suggest you use light blue for test purpose, from here:https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lightblue-bluetooth-low-energy/id557428110?mt=8
and as I know Lollipop 5 installed on nexus 6 and nexus 9 can support peripheral mode, nexus 5 do not support it.
Moto G support peripheral mode?

Comment: yes, almost 6 android devices support peripheral mode right now and Moto G is not one of them. Thanks anyways